# Public variables not showing on inspector?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this script that i have inserted into an object that is a card with no more scripts on it. In the inspector though I cannot change the values of these public variables help?
All the scripts are saved and have been compiled

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CardDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Card card;

    public Text nameText;
    public Text descpritionText;

    public Image artworkImage;

    public Text levelText;
    public Test costText;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Any errors in console? Sounds like it hasn’t compiled

Comment: Yep that was it :(

Answer (score 1):

**There is 3 way which can help you**

1. Ensure that you don't have any compile error in c# scripts
2. Use [System.Serializable] before your class name like

   [System.Serializable]
   public class...{
   }
3. remove regions code before public variables like

   //#if UNITY_ANDROID
   public String androidAdmobAppId;

and if still not working then use your all public variables on top of your class(and private variables on bottom )like

```
public class BillingManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    //#if UNITY_ANDROID
    public String androidAdmobAppId;
    public String androidInterstitalAdUnitId;
    public String androidBannerAdUnitId;
    //#endif
    //#if UNITY_IPHONE
    public String iosAdmobAppId;
    public String iosInterstitalAdUnitId;
    public String iosBannerAdUnitId;
    //#endif
    private BannerView bannerView;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
}
```